# UPDATE 2 rows if both are equal without a SELECT

Tags: mysql

My old table was like this:

```
ID  | A | B |
----+---+---+
112 | 2 | 2 |
345 | 3 | 0 |
```

And now it's like this:

```
ID  | type | value |
----+------+-------+
112 | A    | 2     |
112 | B    | 2     |
345 | A    | 3     |
345 | B    | 0     |
```

So, updating (for example) `A` and `B` if both were equal for a certain ID used to be simple without a select. But in this new type of table, is there a way to achieve the same thing?

In case it's not possible, doing an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` have anything i could use to make it possible? (even if it's a bad practice, this is just for testing purposes!)

Comment: So to make sure I understand... You want to update both the first two rows in the second table because they are both ID 112?

Comment: so ID is NOT a primary key?

Comment: i want to update A and B of the same id (let's say, 112) if both are equal (in this example, it would do it since both A and B of 112 are equal).

And the primary key is (ID,type)

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as solved. If it did not, please explain why it was inadequate and I'll try my best to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should update any rows which have the same value and same ID to 5. You may replace the SET statement with any rows or values you wish.

```
UPDATE new
SET value=5 
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID as outerID 
    FROM new 
    WHERE (
        SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT value)
        FROM new 
        WHERE ID=outerID
    ) = 1
);
```

I'm not sure if sub-queries are against your "no select" rule, but as far as I can tell you will need a select to do the sort of comparison required for this. This will also only work where ALL the rows value colums are the same, not just ANY that are the same.